# Gif not playing over canvas animation on Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, three.js

I'm having this weird bug on Firefox where a gif used as backgound image in not playing when there's a canvas animation. Like on this example. If you check on Webkit, it's totally fine.

```js
const separation = 100, amountX = 70, amountY = 50;
let container, camera, scene, renderer, particles;
let count = 0, windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2, windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2, cameraPosition = 80;

const init = () => {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.x = cameraPosition;
  camera.position.y = 1000;
  camera.position.z = -550;
  camera.zoom = 1.2;
  
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  const numParticles = amountX * amountY;
  const positions = new Float32Array(numParticles * 3);
  const scales = new Float32Array(numParticles);

  let i = 0, j = 0;
  
  for(let ix = 0; ix < amountX; ix++) {
    for(let iy = 0; iy < amountY; iy++) {
      positions[i] = ix * separation - ((amountX * separation ) / 2);
      positions[i + 1] = 0;
      positions[i + 2] = iy * separation - ((amountY * separation ) / 2);

      scales[j] = 1;

      i += 3;
      j ++;
    }
  }
  
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
  geometry.setAttribute('scale', new THREE.BufferAttribute(scales, 1));
  
  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      color: {value: new THREE.Color(0xeae6c3)},
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
  });
  
  particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  scene.add(particles);
  
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setClearColor(0x192735, 1);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  container.style.touchAction = 'none';
  
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
};

const onWindowResize = () => {
  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
};

const render = () => {
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  const positions = particles.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  const scales = particles.geometry.attributes.scale.array;

  let i = 0, j = 0;

  for (let ix = 0; ix < amountX; ix ++) {
    for (let iy = 0; iy < amountY; iy ++) {
      positions[i + 1] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) * 50) + (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) * 50);

      scales[j] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) + 1) * 7 + (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) + 1) * 7;

      i += 3;
      j ++;
    }
  }

  particles.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  particles.geometry.attributes.scale.needsUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  count += 0.011;
};

const animate = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();
};

init();
animate();

const moveCamera = () => {
  cameraPosition = 150;
};
```

```css
body::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/axiol/image/upload/v1612477975/CodePen/noise.gif);
  opacity: 0.05;
  pointer-events: none;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
  attribute float scale;
  void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = scale * (300.0 / - mvPosition.z);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
  uniform vec3 color;
  void main() {
  if (length(gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5, 0.5)) > 0.475 ) discard;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

And I really have no idea where this could come from. On another test I have the same issue. But on this second one the canvas is reacting to the mouse movements. And when the mouse moves, the gif is animated. But once it stop the gif stops.

Anybody already saw that?

Comment: Looks like a recent regression, I can't repro from current stable 85.0.2 on macOs BigSur but after an update of my nightly it also gets stuck (previous version was one month old). I'll try to run a bisect if I've got time, but for the time being can you confirm on which version you made your tests? Also one hackish workaround is to force a repaint every frame: https://jsfiddle.net/qfrcm7db/

Comment: @Kaiido Looks like you might be right. Currently running the 86.0b9. But if I switch to the current live version (85.0.2), looks like it's fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a recent (one week) regression, apparently caused by [this commit](https://hg.mozilla.org/integration/autoland/rev/f0e9e8ac401cb01ae412bf6fd098562892136456).
I did open https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/1692736, let's hope they can fix it before it lands on stable branch.

You can workaround this bug either by disabling WebRender in your own Firefox by going to `about:config` and then toggle `gfx.webrender.force-disabled` to false, or by forcing a re-rendering of the element where the gif is rendered, e.g through a minimal opacity variation in a CSS animation:

```js
const separation = 100, amountX = 70, amountY = 50;
let container, camera, scene, renderer, particles;
let count = 0, windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2, windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2, cameraPosition = 80;

const init = () => {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.x = cameraPosition;
  camera.position.y = 1000;
  camera.position.z = -550;
  camera.zoom = 1.2;
  
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  const numParticles = amountX * amountY;
  const positions = new Float32Array(numParticles * 3);
  const scales = new Float32Array(numParticles);

  let i = 0, j = 0;
  
  for(let ix = 0; ix < amountX; ix++) {
    for(let iy = 0; iy < amountY; iy++) {
      positions[i] = ix * separation - ((amountX * separation ) / 2);
      positions[i + 1] = 0;
      positions[i + 2] = iy * separation - ((amountY * separation ) / 2);

      scales[j] = 1;

      i += 3;
      j ++;
    }
  }
  
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
  geometry.setAttribute('scale', new THREE.BufferAttribute(scales, 1));
  
  const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      color: {value: new THREE.Color(0xeae6c3)},
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
  });
  
  particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  scene.add(particles);
  
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setClearColor(0x192735, 1);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  container.style.touchAction = 'none';
  
  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
};

const onWindowResize = () => {
  windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
};

const render = () => {
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);

  const positions = particles.geometry.attributes.position.array;
  const scales = particles.geometry.attributes.scale.array;

  let i = 0, j = 0;

  for (let ix = 0; ix < amountX; ix ++) {
    for (let iy = 0; iy < amountY; iy ++) {
      positions[i + 1] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) * 50) + (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) * 50);

      scales[j] = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) + 1) * 7 + (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) + 1) * 7;

      i += 3;
      j ++;
    }
  }

  particles.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
  particles.geometry.attributes.scale.needsUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  count += 0.011;
};

const animate = () => {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  render();
};

init();
animate();

const moveCamera = () => {
  cameraPosition = 150;
};
```

```css
/*
  we animate a very small opacity variation
  to force rerendering of the gif image
*/
@keyframes bug1692736 { to { opacity: 0.051; } }
body::after {
  animation: bug1692736 10s infinite;
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/axiol/image/upload/v1612477975/CodePen/noise.gif);
  opacity: 0.05;
  pointer-events: none;
}

canvas {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">
  attribute float scale;
  void main() {
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = scale * (300.0 / - mvPosition.z);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  }
</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">
  uniform vec3 color;
  void main() {
  if (length(gl_PointCoord - vec2(0.5, 0.5)) > 0.475 ) discard;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice workaround, thanks. Should not be hard on perf. I'll follow that ticket, thanks again